# Join conditions using the $lookup operator

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two schemas: bucLaunch - where is stored businessUseCase relations to other businessUseCases. And businessUseCase schema where is informations about businessUseCase (name, desc, state, etc.). One businessUseCase can have multiple relations to other businessUseCase and I need to get a list of businessUseCases which state is not in "closed" state and bucLaunch.businessUseCase is equal to specific Id of businessUseCase._id.

I only got to this point and I dont know why, but aggregate still returning "closed" state.

```
    db.getCollection('bucLaunch').aggregate([
        {
            $addFields: {bucId: {"$toObjectId": "$businessUseCase"}}
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "businessUseCase",
                localField: "bucId",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "output"
        }
        },
        {
            $unwind: "$output"
        },
        {
            $match: { "output.state": { $ne: ["closed"] } }
        }
    )]
```

bucLaunch object looks like this:

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5cab7e9063f03228c0c74acf"),
        "businessUseCase" : "111111111111111111111111",
        "launchingBusinessUseCase" : "222222222222222222222222"
    }
```

and businessUseCase object looks like this:

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("222222222222222222222222"),
        "name" :  "Name",
        "desc" : "Description",
        "state" : "closed"
    }
```

If there will be another businessUseCase like:

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("333333333333333333333333"),
        "name" : "Name2",
        "desc" : "Description2",
        "state" : "inProgress"
    }
```

and another relation object like:

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5cab7e9063f03228c0c74acf"),
        "businessUseCase" : "111111111111111111111111",
        "launchingBusinessUseCase" : "333333333333333333333333"
    }
```

I expecting only businessUseCase list of not closed state like this:

```
    [{
        "_id" : ObjectId("333333333333333333333333"),
        "name" : "Name2",
        "desc" : "Description2",
        "state" : "inProgress"
    }]
```

So, what if I want to get all related businessUseCases for one specific businessUseCase? If I want to get data for specific businessUseCase (id: 111111111111111111111111) I would expect result like:

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("111111111111111111111111"),
        "name" :  "Name1",
        "desc" : "Description1",
        "state" : "closed",
        "notClosedRelatedBucList": [
            {
            "_id" : ObjectId("222222222222222222222222"),
            "name" : "Name2",
            "desc" : "Description2",
            "state" : "inProgress"
            },
            {
            "_id" : ObjectId("444444444444444444444444"),
            "name" : "Name2",
            "desc" : "Description2",
            "state" : "inProgress"
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the last stage (`$match`) of your aggregation pipeline:

```
{
    $match: { "output.state": { $ne: ["closed"] } }
}
```

Here you are trying to match `state` with `["closed"]` (which is an array), that is why it is not matching with docs with `state : "closed"` and its returning those as well. What you should try is to match it with "closed" (String)

Try this in the $match stage :

```
{
    $match: { "output.state": { $ne: "closed" } }
}
```

It should work for you. Hope it helps!

Or if you want to match with one or more strings `(Array of strings)`, you should use `$nin` instead of `$ne` :

```
{
    $match: { "output.state": { $nin: ["closed"] } }
}
```

Read more about [$ne docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) and [$nin docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) for more details.

Comment: It works, thank! I thought I tried, but probably no. Is there any way to get businessUseCase which we ask for and under some key like "relatedBucList" have related not closed businessUseCases? Result should looks like: 
```
{ // main buc
        "_id" : ObjectId("333333333333333333333333"),
        "name" : "Name2",
        "desc" : "Description2",
        "state" : "inProgress",
        "relatedNotClosedBucList": [
             {
                 "name": "Name",
                 "desc" :"Desc,
                 "state" :"inProgress,
             }
         ]
}
```

Comment: I am not able to understand your question properly, can you edit the question and tell me the desired result that you want.\

Comment: Hi, can you help me please? I edited the question. Or can I contact you somewhere personally?

Comment: You can contact me via mail at ravishnkr110@gmail.com